# In HTML unable to execute django if statement

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqhFN.png)

I have created models as shown in the picture. In the index page to display certain content, the member must be active. I am trying to use the if statement.

{% if user.active == True %}
do this...
{% endif %}

The above code is not working, also django is not throwing any error. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When asking a question, try to post actual snippets of code rather than images of code to help us analyze the problem better.

Answer (score 1):

Try simply  **{% if user.active %} do this... {% endif %}**  where user should be the instance of Type1user